# Can the next possible ice age be projected based upon the Milankovitch cycle?

Tags: earth, climate

The [Milankovitch cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milankovitch_cycles)

> describes the collective effects of changes in the Earth's movements upon its climate[.]

By this theory, the Earth is now experiencing an interglacial.

By the theory, when will the interglacial end and the next ice age begin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This paper seems to be discussing what you've asked: http://www.sciencemag.org/content/297/5585/1287.full. The next ice age is expected to begin about 50,000 years from now. However, I think it's still debatable how accurate the predictions of Milankovitch cycles are, and how much of an effect humans are likely to have on this earth system.

Comment: Your link requires paid membership :(

Comment: Try one of the links here: http://scholar.google.co.in/scholar?cluster=6043302048410624765&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5